# Music library deduplicator

Tags: windows, music

My music library is a mess - I've got tons of duplicates through an unfortunate accident.

I'm looking for a good deduplicator. Partial to free, but willing to pay some cash. 
Only real reqs

- Runs on windows
- no malware

Comment: is your music library stored in iTunes??

Comment: itunes? - sometimes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem when I had a partial back-up restore go awry. I fixed it with this. *(I have no association with this company)*

[Fast Duplicate File Finder](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder-About.htm) is a **free** utility for finding duplicate files in a folder and all its sub folders.

The internal preview supports images, videos, music, text and binary files. You can preview your duplicates instantly.

[image]

Comment: Does it deduplicate music files - say if the tags are identical, but the file names are the same?

Comment: How is it at finding duplicates across mapped network drives?

Comment: @Scott Weinstein - I don't think it cares about the file names, tags, or whatever. It does a binary comparison of the contents of the file. It shows the original and duplicate file (grouped together) in the selected directories where you can listen to them and delete the one you select. The older one is selected by default. Check out the tutorial here: http://www.mindgems.com/products/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder-Tutorials.htm

Comment: @jtimberman - I don't remember if used it specifically across networked drives but I don't see why it shouldn't work. If you can access the directories and the data, it should not have any trouble with them.

Answer (score 1):

Another similar program is [Clonespy](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC8QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.clonespy.com%2F%3FFeatures&ei=SoP8Trq_OOrHsQLbxNHIAQ&usg=AFQjCNFTB_h8HBMySiozcbaai4e3hF0j4Q)

It's also freeware.  Fast Duplicate File Finder is now Trialware.